# Can I convert nested lists to a data frame without altering column names?

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I'm investigating the abililty for R to read files with unfriendly column names. One file type I'm looking at is JSON, which can be read with `jsonlite` or `rjson`. The `jsonlite` package works wonderfully and is not involved in my question.

To start with, here are two pieces of data that contain unfriendly column names. This is a small example of my actual data, which also contains numeric columns.

```r
library(rjson)
library(dplyr)

csv_file <- 'English,中文 (Simplified),中文 (Traditional),فارسى,Русский язык,Tiếng Việt
Alice,蔼,佩佩,آیسا,Аделаида,Anh Đào
Amy,安,姗姗,افسانه,Анна,Anh Thư
Barbara,芳,安娜,اندیشه,Валентина,Bấc
Carol,淑芬,寶珠,نادره,Вера,Bạch Tuyểt
Elizabeth,菊,小蘭,بهشته,Зинаида,Bảo Châu
Jaclyn,兰,小鳳,تبسم,Изабэлла,Chín
Jane,丽丽,惠娟,توسکا,Капитолина,Cúc
Judy,梅,淑儀,روژین,Лариса,Dậu
Katie,敏,燕玲,زرّین تاج,Маргарита,Diễm'

json_file <- '[{"English":"Alice","中文 (Simplified)":"蔼","中文 (Traditional)":"佩佩","فارسى":"آیسا","Русский язык":"Аделаида","Tiếng Việt":"Anh Đào"},
{"English":"Amy","中文 (Simplified)":"安","中文 (Traditional)":"姗姗","فارسى":"افسانه","Русский язык":"Анна","Tiếng Việt":"Anh Thư"},
{"English":"Barbara","中文 (Simplified)":"芳","中文 (Traditional)":"安娜","فارسى":"اندیشه","Русский язык":"Валентина","Tiếng Việt":"Bấc"},
{"English":"Carol","中文 (Simplified)":"淑芬","中文 (Traditional)":"寶珠","فارسى":"نادره","Русский язык":"Вера","Tiếng Việt":"Bạch Tuyểt"},
{"English":"Elizabeth","中文 (Simplified)":"菊","中文 (Traditional)":"小蘭","فارسى":"بهشته","Русский язык":"Зинаида","Tiếng Việt":"Bảo Châu"},
{"English":"Jaclyn","中文 (Simplified)":"兰","中文 (Traditional)":"小鳳","فارسى":"تبسم","Русский язык":"Изабэлла","Tiếng Việt":"Chín"},
{"English":"Jane","中文 (Simplified)":"丽丽","中文 (Traditional)":"惠娟","فارسى":"توسکا","Русский язык":"Капитолина","Tiếng Việt":"Cúc"},
{"English":"Judy","中文 (Simplified)":"梅","中文 (Traditional)":"淑儀","فارسى":"روژین","Русский язык":"Лариса","Tiếng Việt":"Dậu"},
{"English":"Katie","中文 (Simplified)":"敏","中文 (Traditional)":"燕玲","فارسى":"زرّین تاج","Русский язык":"Маргарита","Tiếng Việt":"Diễm"}]'
```

I can create an unaltered data frame from the CSV data easily (but notice the `check.names = FALSE`), and this is the standard that I compare with other files to see if they are read in correctly. I additionally read the JSON data using `rjson::fromJSON()`.

```r
# make data frame from csv data
df_csv = read.csv(text = csv_file, check.names = FALSE)

# read json data using rjson
# giving a list of lists
raw_json <- rjson::fromJSON(json_file)
```

The `rjson` package returns a nested list of lists, which means that making it a data frame with something simple like `as.data.frame()` won't work. I thought of using `rbind()` inside of `do.call()` to create a data frame, which I'll then compare to the CSV data using `dplyr::setdiff()`. In this case I can use `check.names = FALSE` inside the `data.frame()` function.

```r
# make data frame from json data using data.frame and rbind
df_json1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, raw_json), check.names = FALSE)

# compare using setdiff
setdiff(df_csv, df_json1)
```

The `setdiff()` comparison gives an error because all the columns in the the JSON-sourced data frame are lists.

```r
Error in `setdiff()`:
! `x` and `y` are not compatible.
✖ Incompatible types for column `English`: character vs list.
✖ Incompatible types for column `中文 (Simplified)`: character vs list.
✖ Incompatible types for column `中文 (Traditional)`: character vs list.
✖ Incompatible types for column `فارسى`: character vs list.
✖ Incompatible types for column `Русский язык`: character vs list.
✖ Incompatible types for column `Tiếng Việt`: character vs list.
```

After some reading and discussing, I discovered that there's a version of `rbind()` for data frames, `rbind.data.frame()`. So, I tried using that inside of my `do.call()`, obviating the need for the surrounding `data.frame()`.

```r
# make data frame from json using rbind.data.frame
# gives a data frame whose columns are vectors
df_json2 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, raw_json)

#compare using setdiff
setdiff(df_csv, df_json2)
```

This causes an error because the names were changed to be R friendly. I no longer have the ability to use `check.names = FALSE`. (Do I? I looked and can't find a way.)

```r
Error in `setdiff()`:
! `x` and `y` are not compatible.
✖ Cols in `y` but not `x`: `中文..Simplified.`, `中文..Traditional.`,
  `Русский.язык`, `Tiếng.Việt`.
✖ Cols in `x` but not `y`: `中文 (Simplified)`, `中文 (Traditional)`, `Русский
  язык`, `Tiếng Việt`.
```

Here is my dilemma. I'd like to create a data frame identical to the CSV-generated one, but can't seem to get it using these approaches. **How can I take the output of `rjson::fromJSON` and arrive at the CSV file?**

NB: I realize the column name changes seem to only be an issue of spaces and parentheses. Things are cleaner because I've pasted all the Unicode here in the post. When I read data files from external sources, much stranger things happen. For example, the `Tiếng Việt` column gets changed to `Tiê.ng.Viê.t`, I suppose because of the multiple diacritics. Hence, my question of comparing the files without having to guess all the things that can go wrong and preprocessing them out.

Comment: FWIW, `jsonlite::fromJSON` parses that json-string exactly as you are expecting.

Comment: Can confrim, `jsonlite::fromJSON(json_file)` output is identical to `df_csv`. Like `identical(df_csv, df_json)` identical.

Comment: I thank you both for your efforts, but I had determined this already, which is why I said up front “The jsonlite package works wonderfully and is not involved in my question.” Please don’t take this as rudeness—I’m just wondering if and how one would deal with the rjson output.

Comment: `purrr::map_dfr(raw_json, dplyr::as_tibble)` would do that as well. Are you limiting yourself to base R + `{rjson}` with this task?

Comment: No, not at all. But I’m not great with purrr, so thanks for the idea!

Comment: @Brian, I also notice that map_df &c have been superseded, so I'll try to write your solution using plain-old map() funcitons.

Comment: @SciolismApparently it could be done with `lapply` and `do.call(rbind, ...)`, the key is that you're coercing the lists to dataframes with `as_tibble` instead of base-R standards.